# ¿Por qué me da distinto resultado en Python, si es lo mismo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matemáticas

Estaba practicando algunas cosas básicas de Python, sobre patrones de acumulación.
E intentando hacer algo, de dos maneras distintas, pensando que me iba a dar el mismo resultado, me dio distinto.

Por un lado,

```
w = [1,2,3]
z = w
w += [4,5]
z = z + [6]
print(w)
print(z)
```

```
w = [1, 2, 3]
z = w
w += [4, 5]
z += [6]
print(w)
print(z)
```

La diferencia entre la primera y la segunda es que en la primera use `z = z+ [6]` y en la segunda use `z += [6]`.

En la primera me da de resultado `w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` y `z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

En la segunda me da de resultado `w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` y `z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué me da distinto `w`, si es lo mismo hacer `z = z + [6]`, que hacer `z += [6]`.

Aparentemente no es lo mismo, sino daría el mismo resultado.

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La sintaxis `z += [6]` equivale a `z.extend([6])`, que en este caso sería similar a `z.append(6)`. En cualquiera de estos casos la referencia `z` sigue apuntando a la misma lista a la que apuntaba inicialmente (la cual por cierto es la misma lista apuntada por `w`). Pero la lista en sí va creciendo.

En cambio en el momento que haces `z = lo que sea`, estás cambiando la referencia `z` para que apunte a otro sitio. En este caso concreto le haces apuntar al resultado de `z + [6]`, lo cual crea una lista nueva (y ya `z` deja de apuntar a la lista a la que apunta `w`).

La ejecución dentro de python tutor del [primer caso](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=w%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%0Az%20%3D%20w%0Aw%20%2B%3D%20%5B4,%205%5D%0Az%20%2B%3D%20%5B6%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) que extiende la lista termina con este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que la ejecución del  [segundo caso](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=w%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3%5D%0Az%20%3D%20w%0Aw%20%2B%3D%20%5B4,5%5D%0Az%20%3D%20z%20%2B%20%5B6%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) que crea una lista nueva termina así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota final**. Es más eficiente `z+=[6]` si no te preocupan los efectos secundarios de estar modificando indirectamente la lista `w` (por ejemplo, porque `z` sea la única referencia que mantienes). La sintaxis `z = z + [6]` implica copiar la lista original para crear una nueva a la que añadirle el 6, por lo que es más ineficiente.

Así, por ejemplo, un bucle como este:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1000):
  lista = lista + [i]
```

es mucho más ineficiente que este otro:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1000):
   lista += [i]
```

(Este es un ejemplo artificial, sería aún más óptimo hacer `lista = list(range(1000))` en este caso)

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia es sutil, pero existe.

Al hacer `z += [6]` estás agregándole a Z, sin dudas. Pero `z + [6]` implica crear un nuevo conjunto con los elementos de los dos operandos. Ese conjunto, *no es z*, es un conjunto nuevo. Así que luego ese conjunto nuevo lo asignas a z.... pero el conjunto que *antes* era z (o sea, el mismo que sigue siendo w) no se ve afectado.